# How to write a VPN extension for Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating an extension for Google Chrome, its primary use being to redirect traffic from my computer to a Raspberry Pi at my home. Being new to .json and javascript definitely does not help, so are there any tutorials available/any example code I can play with?

I've tried googling (and even checked the second and third pages) but all to no avail, as I only get results to buy NordVPN and to buy/use other associated VPNs.

My current browser extension is pretty bare, all it does is alert whenever you navigate to a new page.

```
{
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
```

```
// content.js
alert("Hello from your Chrome extension!")
```

That's pretty much my code, it's obviously not the most complicated code in the world, but i'm only a beginner. So, are there any tutorials available/any example code I can play with?

Comment: The existing VPN extensions simply install a rule for their proxy server via chrome.proxy API or use chrome.webRequest to redirect the URLs, you can easily find a lot of examples for both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get that level of control from within the browser.  To set up network drivers and such needed for VPN, you have to install other software on the system.  (Sure, you can control it from an extension, but the extension itself can't be your VPN client.)

You might consider setting up a normal HTTP/HTTPS proxy server.  That will allow you to re-route all of your web traffic, aside from WebRTC connections.

If you're really insistent on doing this with an extension only, you'll have to make a Service Worker to intercept traffic... and then do all of the work to proxy that data via a protocol of choice or your creation to/from the server.

Comment: Where can I read more about this?

There are lot of VPN extensions in chrome store, which installing just like extension.

Comment: @BorisPaschenko You could inspect the source code of any of those extensions to see exactly what they're doing or not doing.